# Select multidimensional arrays from form with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, arrays, forms, jquery-selectors

I tried to select a multidimensional form item with JQuery. But when I try to alert its value I just get an `undefined`.

This is my form:

```
    <select name='item[1][name]'>
       <option value='1'>Name 1</option>
       <option value='2'>Name 2</option>
       <option value='3'>Name 3</option>
       <option value='4'>Name 4</option>
    </select>

    <input type='text' name='item[1][id]' class='text' />
```

When I click on submit button, I try to select all my form elements.

I successfully selected the text input field with:

```
var item1i = $('input[name="item[1][id]"]');
var personi = $(item1i).val();
```

But when I try to select the `select` tag like this:

```
var item1n = $('input[name="item[1][name]"]');
var personn = $(item1n).val();
```

When I alert `personi` the right value is shown. But when I alert `personn` I get `undefined`.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You're trying to select the "select" tag with an "input" selector.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `$('select[name="item[1][name]"]');`

Or alternatively, `$(':input[name="item[1][name]"]');`

`input` will only select the elements with `input` tag, so for your select you have to use the `select` tag.

Alternatively jquery provides the special `:input` selector that returns any form element (input texts, selects, checkboxes, textarea,etc), so you can use that too.

Comment: don't mind that I tried to solve this problem like for two hours and didn't even see that i use input for a select element.

Answer (score 0):

```
var item1n = $('input[name="item[1][name]"]');
```

you've the wrong selector here. Try this

```
var item1n = $('select[name="item[1][name]"]');
```